# `.dev` TLD resolves to 127.0.0.1

Tags: dns, hosts-file

My Mac (Mojave 10.14) is unable to access any website with a [.dev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dev) domain name, such as [get.dev](https://get.dev/). I tried running `$ ping get.dev` and got the following output:

```
PING get.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.161 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.189 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
^C
--- get.dev ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.044/0.114/0.189/0.059 ms
```

I know it's been popular to remap `.dev` to localhost, and thought I might have done that at some point in the past and forgot about it. However, when I run `$ cat /etc/hosts`:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I'm not sure where to continue troubleshooting this. Are there any other `hosts` files that might add additional entries?

EDIT: My DNS is set up to use 1.1.1.1, according to [their instructions](https://1.1.1.1/dns/#setup-instructions).

EDIT: **More troubleshooting below.**

`$ dig get.dev`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> get.dev
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58743
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;get.dev.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
get.dev.        300 IN  A   216.239.32.29

;; Query time: 44 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May 15 14:35:46 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

`curl -v get.dev`:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: get.dev/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to get.dev port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to get.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

Why would `curl` try 127.0.0.1 when `dig` returns 216.239.32.29?

Comment: Have you tried to clear your DNS cache?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I tried `$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`. Did I get that right? If so, clearing the DNS cache didn't make a difference.

Comment: Maybe your upstream DNS server serves you the wrong IP?

Comment: @mtak After posting the question, I tried switching to `1.1.1.1` (following the instructions at https://1.1.1.1/dns/#setup-instructions) and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: What’s the Mac’s host name? You need to check the mDNSResponder log to find out where it’s resolving this from.

Comment: output of `dig get.dev`?

Comment: Hey, try this: `dig @1.1.1.1 get.dev` versus `dig get.dev`. See if you get different results.

Comment: Running `dig`:

```;; ANSWER SECTION:

get.dev.  199 IN A 216.239.32.29``` It says it's using 1.1.1.1, `dig @1.1.1.1 get.dev` returns virtually the same (different TTL)

Comment: You know it's resolving how it should be if you use dig and a specific nameserver. So the issue is likely on your machine, network or your ISP. Do other machines on your network (e.g. a phone connected to your WLAN) show the same symptoms? Did you verify that your configuration was changed to use 1.1.1.1 and not e.g. a DHCP supplied nameserver?

Comment: @Seth It's absolutely a problem on the machine, I've reproduced the problem on two different wifi networks, and other computers/phones on the same network work. No .dev URL I've tried will load on this machine regardless of network. I'm not sure what your last sentence means, when I open System Prefs > Network > Advanced > DNS it has the four IPs listed at https://1.1.1.1/dns/#setup-instructions

Comment: @DanielB How do I check the mDNSResponder log?

Comment: @last-child, can you run `scutil --dns`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

run `scutil --dns` and check if you found something like:

```
There was entry:
 resolver #8
  domain   : dev
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)
```

if is this case you can run `rm -f /etc/resolver/dev` to remove it

Comment: This solved it, thank you. `# Lovingly generated by Pow`, apparently this is [still the default behavior of Pow.cx](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_3.1)